# can't send signals to a specific user

Tags: django, django-models

i'm sending notifications to a user via django notifications. And i have username regex working on the html so anyone comments with **@username** it will post and the html is linkable so click on the @username it will take him to the username profile page. Now i am using django signals to match the username and print out the username. but when i use notify to send the notification. it does not work.
 models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reply = models.ForeignKey('Comment', null=True, related_name='replies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='comments-pics', null=True, blank=True)
voice_record = models.FileField(upload_to='voice-comments', null=True, blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__ (self):
    return '{}.{}'.format(self.post.title, str(self.user.username))


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def Comment_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args,**kwargs):
    if created and not instance.parent:
    user_regex = r'@(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)'
    m = re.search(user_regex, instance.content)
    if m:
        try:
            recipient = User.objects.get(username=m.group('username'))
        except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            pass
        else:
            notify.send(instance.user, recipient=recipient, actor=instance.user, verb='mention you in a post', target=instance, nf_type='tagged_by_one_user')

post_save.connect(Comment_save_receiver, sender=post)
```

Comment: Please provide more information regarding it not working. What have you tried, what did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Do you have any additional debugging context?

Comment: Please also correct your indentations to match exactly what's in your code. That could potentially cause problems for you and is hard to tell right now.

Comment: Sir, it should send a notification to the user like a user mention a user in the comments

Comment: I'm using django notifications to send notification to a user if anyone like or comment..it notifies them.. and the comment form is in a ajax form method ..so i could not get the actual error

Comment: If any error occurs it prevent the form from submitting..but its not getting any error. I have the problem with the instances.

Comment: Have you identified which line is being problematic?

Comment: No i can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved. i did wrong with the signal portion. it will be:

```
def comment_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args,**kwargs):
if created:
user_regex = r'@(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)'
m = re.search(user_regex, instance.content)
if m:
    try:
        recipient = User.objects.get(username=m.group('username'))
    except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
        pass
    else:
        notify.send(instance.user, recipient=recipient, actor=instance.user, verb='mention you in a post', target=instance.post, nf_type='tagged_by_one_user')

post_save.connect(comment_save_receiver, sender=Comment)
```